# D3 JS - How to draw horizontal force graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a force graph as shown in below image. I am checking the graph given at this link [force tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500). This tree is vertical. I want it horizontal so that I can achieve the graph shown in the image. I tried to play with the code but was not able to make it horizontal. Is there any way I can achieve the graph shown in the image.

desired force graph
[image]

Comment: use d3v5 and use the force-X for the small nodes

Comment: Thanks rioV8 for your answer. I did the small change suggested by Shushan and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the tree horizontal is actually quite simple in the given example.

The `tick` function is responsible for assigning positions to each node, and it modifies the `y` value of the nodes between levels. Simply change it to modify the `x` value of the nodes.

Like so:

```
function tick(e) {
    var k = 6 * e.alpha;

    // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
    link
        // Swapped here from y to x
        .each(function(d) { d.source.x -= k, d.target.x += k; })
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  }
```

Comment: I understood the use of tick now. Thanks Shushan. It is working now.

Comment: This is working for d3 v3 only and not for d3 v5. Shushan, do you know how to do this version 5?